# How to save I figure as a image matlab?

Tags: matlab, figure

I want to save the figure in terms of filename. How can I do this? I use some saveas commands but I couldn't modify it for filename.

```
imagefilename='lena_gray_256.tif';
maskfilename='M3.tif';
filename = [imagefilename maskfilename];
%Creating plots
imshow(ML)
title('Masked image')
```

Regards;

Answer (score 1):

```
imagefilename='lena_gray_256.tif';
maskfilename='M3.tif';
filename = [imagefilename maskfilename];
%Creating plots
imshow(ML)
title('Masked image')
saveas( gcf, filename, 'jpg' );
```

solved=)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `imwrite`:

```
%//After your code insert
imwrite(frame2im(getframe(gcf)),filename);
```

The command should recognize the image type by checking the extension.
You might want to change the background color of your figure to white before writing the image:

```
set(gcf,'Color','w')
imwrite(frame2im(getframe(gcf)),filename);
```

Instead of `gcf` you can use the function handle of your figure.